# Merge two arrays avoiding O(n^2) complexity

Tags: arrays

Given two arrays, farmers and collections, I want to be able to merge the farmer information to each collection when farmer_id in the collection is equal to id in farmers. if there is no id of the farmer that matches farmer_id in the collection then that collection should have a an empty farmer object

```
const farmers = [{
        id: 10,
        name: 'John Doe',
        email: 'jdoe@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'James Bond',
        email: 'james@gmail.com'
    }
]
```

```
const collections = [{
        id: 9,
        name: 'Book',
        farmer_id: 10,
        date: 'June'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Game',
        farmer_id: 11,
        date: 'July'
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Car',
        farmer_id: 10,
        date: 'August'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'Wristwatches',
        farmer_id: 20,
        date: 'August'
    }
]
```

## The result should be in this format below

```
const result = [{
        id: 9,
        name: 'Book',
        farmer_id: 10,
        date: 'June',
        farmer: {
            id: 10,
            name: 'John Doe',
            email: 'jdoe@gmail.com'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Game',
        farmer_id: 11,
        date: 'July',
        farmer: {
            id: 11,
            name: 'James Bond',
            email: 'james@gmail.com'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Car',
        farmer_id: 10,
        date: 'August',
        farmer: {
            id: 10,
            name: 'John Doe',
            email: 'jdoe@gmail.com'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'Wristwatches',
        farmer_id: 20,
        date: 'August',
        farmer: {}
    }
]
```

This is what i have been able to come up with but am stuck right now

```
function mapper(farmers, collectors) {
    for (let k = 0; k < farmers.length; k++) {
        const idToFarmerInfo = {};
        idToFarmerInfo[farmers[k].id] = farmers[k];
        for (let j = 0; j < collectors.length; j++) {
            let mapper = idToFarmerInfo[collectors[j].farmer_id];
            farmers[mapper] = collectors[j]
        }
    }
    return farmers
}
```

[i followed this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304296/sorting-an-array-based-on-another-arrays-order-quickly) as am trying to avoid O of N squared but O of N complexity

Comment: What *specifically* about this has you "stuck"?

Comment: I noticed I can extract the farmer object by the famer_id of the collection using the map. But am looking for a way to append the extracted farmer into the collection as in the case of the result array above. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a better *performance* you could create a `hash` of *farmers* where the `complexity` is `O(N)` because we're *iterating* the `farmers` list *only once*.

```js
const farmers = [{ id: 10, name: 'John Doe', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com' }, { id: 11, name: 'James Bond', email: 'james@gmail.com' } ]; const collections = [{ id: 9, name: 'Book', farmer_id: 10, date: 'June' }, { id: 10, name: 'Game', farmer_id: 11, date: 'July' }, { id: 13, name: 'Car', farmer_id: 10, date: 'August' }, { id: 11, name: 'Wristwatches', farmer_id: 20, date: 'August' } ]

var farmers_hash = farmers.reduce((hash, item) => {
  hash[item.id] = item;
  return hash;
}, {});

console.log(farmers_hash);
```

The following step is to *build* the desired `output` by assigning one farmer using *hash* keys.

This can be *achieved* using `map` method in combination with `Object.assign`.

```js
const farmers = [{ id: 10, name: 'John Doe', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com' }, { id: 11, name: 'James Bond', email: 'james@gmail.com' } ]; const collections = [{ id: 9, name: 'Book', farmer_id: 10, date: 'June' }, { id: 10, name: 'Game', farmer_id: 11, date: 'July' }, { id: 13, name: 'Car', farmer_id: 10, date: 'August' }, { id: 11, name: 'Wristwatches', farmer_id: 20, date: 'August' } ]

var farmers_hash = farmers.reduce((hash, item) => {
  hash[item.id] = item;
  return hash;
}, {});

var result = collections.map((item) => {
  item.farmer = Object.assign({}, farmers_hash[item.farmer_id])
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

As you can see the *final* complexity is `O(N) + O(M)` where `N` is the length of `farmers` array and `M` is the length of `collections` array.

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what I was trying to achieve. Creating a map of the farmer id to the farmer info then use that to append to collections array

Answer (score 2):

Demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-append-object-in-first-array-to-second-array-when-a-conditio)

You can use a more declarative approach and use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const result = collections.map(collection => {
  return {
    ...collection,
    farmer: farmers.find(farmer => collection.farmer_id == farmer.id) || {}
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The complexity for this solution is `O(M*N*logN)` if the find method is based on binary search.

Comment: Thanks it worked , it should be farmers.find(farmer => collection.farmer_id == farmer.id)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map` collection to have `O(N)` of access to desired farmer by `id`. Then mapping becomes faster in terms of performance:

```
const unique = new Map(farmers.map(f=> [f.id, f]));

const result = collections.map(s => ({
    ...s, farmer_id: unique.get(s.farmer_id) || s.farmer_id
}))
```

Now mapping of `collections` has complexity `O(N)`. However, do not forget to sum complexity of making unique farmers. The overall complexity is `O(N) + O(M)`.

An example:

```js
const farmers = [{
    id: 10,
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@gmail.com'
},
{
    id: 11,
    name: 'James Bond',
    email: 'james@gmail.com'
}
];

const collections = [{
    id: 9,
    name: 'Book',
    farmer_id: 10,
    date: 'June'
},
{
    id: 10,
    name: 'Game',
    farmer_id: 11,
    date: 'July'
},
{
    id: 13,
    name: 'Car',
    farmer_id: 10,
    date: 'August'
},
{
    id: 11,
    name: 'Wristwatches',
    farmer_id: 20,
    date: 'August'
}
];

const unique = new Map(farmers.map(f=> [f.id, f]));

const result = collections.map(s => ({
    ...s, farmer_id: unique.get(s.farmer_id) || s.farmer_id
}))

console.log(result);
```